# Transcription assistance for a baptism record from 1620 in Mihla, Germany

Tags: palaeography, church-records, kurrent, german

The surnames here look quite interesting for two of my lines, but I'm having difficulty reading the writing.

Can you fix the errors in my transcription?

[image: Handwritten excerpt in German]

```
Sommabeu aliheniradias domini getauff Ni
claus Haserten imo vicino zudo fuugs tochter,
et guidem primogenitas in zdo matrimonio,
Eliae genantt Clara, Hub meine hausfrau
aus der h. Eauffe.  Die audere ward genantt
Elisabetha, der en tauppage war Meister heinrich
Illerts, metzigers alhier hausfrau, Elisabeth.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I can read:

I have difficulties reading the day, as the paper is damaged here.

> Sonnabend xxx ...rdias Domini getauft Ni

vicino means "near", so the word before that is maybe a profession or related to a place (or simply a word meaning "from" or "lives", I don't read Latin well).

> claus haserten ...imo? [primo?] vicino zwo junge töchter,

> et guidem primogenitas in sito matrimonis,

> eine genannt clara, hub meine hausfraw

> aus der h. tauffe die andere ward genannt

> elisabeth, deren taufpath war meister heinrichs

I'm not sure about the last name, but the profession would be a butcher

> illerts? metzigers alhier hausfraw, elisabeth`

Comment: Thanks, that made it comprehensible enough.  :)  The surnames Hasert and Illert both make sense in that town's context as well.